# How to populate Breadcrumbs in Angular js with links?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

i have created a grid on double clicking the item, grid traverse inside that folder so according to it i want to populate breadcrumbs. I am not getting any solution how do i start it. 
My demo link below:

when clicked on 'Moroni'
then it should update breadcrumbs by 
Home / Moroni

Comment: here my demo link: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZwVsWpUy2tXM8dYy2io?p=preview

Comment: check this out :http://jsfiddle.net/enricopulatzo/CY37S/

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't understand your filtering behaviour, here is what to do:

Setup your gridOptions:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    selectedItems:[],
    multiSelect: false,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    rowTemplate: rowTempl,
  };
```

Note the `selectedItems` array and that `multiSelect` is set to `false` so you can only select 1 row at a time.

In your html change the breadcrumb div to:

```
<div id="Breadcrumbs"> Home /{{gridOptions.selectedItems[0].name}}</div>
```

It seems that Plunker is down at the moment, so I can give you no forked example...

[Plunker is back again](http://plnkr.co/edit/wSSyZE5j5Ce9gB7dnMU0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @mainguy let me try whenever plunker is back.

Comment: I think Plunker is working again, but it takes bloody ages to load... Out of 10 tries I got 3 connections... Keep on trying!